# Многофайловая программа

Tags: c++, компоновщик, модульность

Делал простенькую игру в консоли одним файлом, сейчас же хочу разбить её на модули в разных cpp файлах. Проблема в том, что мне нужно из разных cpp файлов работать с четко определенными функциями в главном cpp файле. Уже пробовал что-то написать, но вылезает всегда проблема двойного определения. Как быть? Буду рад любым рекомендациям.

**Файл Header.h:**

```
#ifndef HEADER_ 
#define HEADER_ 

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int x_pos;

int getX();
int func();

#endif
```

**TEST.cpp:**

```
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    x_pos = 12;
    cout << getX();

    cout << func();
}

int getX() {
    return 111;
}
```

**Sourse.cpp:**

```
#include "Header.h"

int func() {
    return getX();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вынесите объявления функций в заголовочный файл, который и включайте в .cpp-файлы. В заголовочном добавьте защиту от повторного включения, типа `#pragma once`.. Без конкретного примера кода определить, в чем конкретно ваша ошибка - проблематично, приходится гадать...

Comment: Приведите [mre] ошибки

Comment: @dIm0n, добавил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
int x_pos;
```

на

```
extern int x_pos;
```

и добавьте

```
int x_pos;
```

в **один** из .cpp-файлов.

Или напишите вместо

```
int x_pos;
```

это:

```
inline int x_pos;
```

Дело в том, что просто

```
int x_pos;
```

это не просто объявление, но и определение глобальной переменной `x_pos`, в результате чего она оказывается определена в двух .cpp-файлах.

Если в программе, как и в примере, переменная используется только в одном .cpp-файле, то там ее и определите, не вставляя в .h-файл...

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Как я понял, к каждому из моих cpp файлов нужно писать отдельный заголовочный файл, в котором будет определение только используемых в данном cpp файле переменных и функций?

Comment: Нет, единственного заголовочного файла достаточно. Деление на разные заголовочные файлы в больших проектах не техническое, а скорее логическое - по предназначению содержащихся в них функций/классов.

Comment: Вообще глобальные переменные не слишком хорошая вещь. А модули не так пишутся. Модули через export module M; export class T; итд

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, не поделитесь источником? Я б почитал. Было бы здорово найти статейку именно про реально правильное разбитие программы на файлы.

Comment: Гугл есть. Если так хочется использовать инклуды, то можно пихать в .h определения классов. .hpp реализации темплейтовых функций. .cpp реализации не темплейтовых функций. Как делать глобальный класс уже сказали. А вообще лучше знать что такое инклуд, и для чего pimpl и forward declaration. И ещё: инклуд гвард уже давно не стоит юзать, онц все 3 компилятора поддержисают.

Comment: Забавно, впервые узнал, что имеется только три компилятора C++ :)